# Unable to highlight error text in Excel 2007 Userform Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in Excel2007 that contains a number of textboxes. Some of these require dates and I want to validate that the date is entered in a correct format. If not, I want to retain the focus in the specific textbox; highlight the incorrect entry and allow the user to retype a correct date. Most of this functionality works, but the one issue I cannot solve is that the 'error date' - although obviously selected as immediately using the 'delete' key after acknowledging the message box does, indeed, delete it - will NOT highlight.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtDOB_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If txtDOB.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
If IsDate(txtDOB.Text) Then
 txtDOB.Value = Format(txtDOB.Text, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
Else
MsgBox "Does not appear to be a valid date. A date should be in the format dd/mm/yy i.e 25/12/13.", vbInformation, "Invalid Date"
    Cancel = True
    With txtDOB
        .SetFocus 'probably not necessary after setting Cancel=True
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
 End If
End Sub
```

I have looked long and hard at many replies to similar issues, but none seem to address this simple issue! It is NOT that my error date ISN'T being selected - it is, as I mention above. It is just that although selected, there is no obvious 'flag' via text highlighting to the user that this specific text is now ready and able to be corrected. I am sure there is a simple answer to this dilemma, and I will be very grateful if someone can advise me what it is!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a form not updating after I changed data on it and I only solved it with a `Repaint`.

Ironically, I was trying to deselect the text so it didn't appear highlighted :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just solved my own problem! If I make sure the HideSelection property of the textbox is **false** the code - and, most importantly, the highlighting works!